# How to enable 802.1X security for Ethernet on Raspbian 10?

Tags: raspbian, networking, networkmanager

On a different host running Ubuntu 18.04 I'm using the Network Manager GUI to configure the 802.1X Security for my **Ethernet** interface (eth0), leading to /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections having these lines:

```
[802-1x]
eap=md5;
identity=userid
password=***
```

Now, clearly Raspbian is not Ubuntu, so there's no Network Manager.
Therefore I wonder how can I do the same on my Raspberry Pi 4 running Raspbian 10 (buster)?

Answer (score 0):

802.1x authentication is handled by `wpa_supplicant`. `man wpa_supplicant.conf` and scroll down to the 802.1x example.

Answer (score 0):

There is a more elaborate explanation on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Network802.1xAuthentication or https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/WPA_supplicant.

Basically, it has the following steps:

- add the network to `/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf`
- start `wpa_supplicant` for the interface eth0
- sometimes, it is necessary to do some extra steps.